# Topology on cohomology of a sheaf of topological groups

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, sheaf-theory, topological-groups, sheaf-cohomology

Let $X$ be a topological space and $\mathcal{F}$ be a sheaf of commutative topological groups on $X$. I am interested in the following question:

- Is there a natural way to introduce topology on $H^i(X, \mathcal{F})$?

My guess is that  for each open covering $\mathcal{U}$ the space of Čech cochains $\check{C}(\mathcal{U}, \mathcal{F})$ can be endowed with the compact-open topology. This topology can be restricted to the space of closed cochains, descends to $H^i(\mathcal{U}, \mathcal{F})$ and induce direct limit topology on $H^i(X, \mathcal{F})$. But does this construction make sense? Say, is it functorial? Is it true that $H^i(X, \mathcal{F})$ are commutative topological groups (with respect to the natural group operation)? Are the other reasonable choices of topology on Čech complex? Can they lead to other topologies?

And what is the best reference on this topic?

I don't think that this is important, but in the situation I am interested in, the space $X$ is a (finite-dimensional) manifold and $\mathcal{F}$ is a sheaf of Lie groups.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both cases ($F$ is a sheaf of abelian topological groups or abelian Lie groups) can be treated using the same machinery.

The Yoneda embedding embeds abelian Lie groups as a fully faithful subcategory of the category of sheaves of abelian groups on the site of smooth manifolds, and the embedding functor preserves small limits.
I refer to the latter category as the category of *abelian smooth groups*.
This category is complete and cocomplete.
It is, in fact, better behaved than the category of abelian topological groups, since the latter category is not an abelian category:
a morphism of abelian topological groups can have a trivial kernel and cokernel, without being an isomorphism.
On the other hand, the category of smooth groups is abelian.

From now on, we work either with presheaves of chain complexes of abelian topological groups or presheaves of chain complexes of smooth groups.

The category of such chain complexes can be equipped with the projective
model structure transferred from simplicial topological spaces
respectively simplicial sheaves on the site of smooth manifolds.

The category of presheaves of such chain complexes can itself be equipped
with the projective model structure,
which can then be further localized with respect to Čech nerves of open covers.
Fibrant objects in the resulting model category are presheaves
of chain complexes that satisfy the homotopy descent condition.

The fibrant replacement functor computes the (hyper)cohomology of sheaves.
More precisely, if $F→RF$ is a fibrant replacement of the sheaf $F$,
then $H^i(X,F)=H^i(Γ(X,RF))$.

The resulting cohomology theory is essentially (a reformulation of) the Segal–Mitchison cohomology in the topological case,
or its [smooth version by Brylinski](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0011069).

In particular, the cohomology group $H^i(X,F)$ is by definition
a smooth (respectively topological) group, since $H^i$ is computed in the category of smooth (respectively topological) groups.

Comment: I didn't understand you answer completely yet, but are you claiming that if $\mathcal{F}$ is a sheaf of Lie groups, then $H^i(X, \mathcal{F})$ are Lie groups? This confuses me a lot, say I don't understand why $H^i(X, \mathcal{F})$ should be Hausdorff.

Comment: @V.Rogov: The object $H^i(X,F)$ is a smooth group, i.e., a sheaf of abelian groups on the site of smooth manifolds.  If this sheaf is representable, then we can identify $H^i(X,F)$ with a Lie group.  Otherwise $H^i(X,F)$ is a smooth group that is not a Lie group.  So one point of my answer is that the category of Lie groups must be enlarged (following Grothendieck's advice) to a good category (smooth groups in this case).

Comment: I guess the recentlyd-defined condensed group would be a similar strategy, also involving enlarging the category of topological groups to a category of sheaves of groups on a site.